# Flask, Python - Increase timeout length on Heroku app

Tags: python, heroku, flask, timeout

I'm building a web app using Flask and hosting it on Heroku. My app scrapes the web—so it can take anywhere from a few seconds to 20 minutes, depending on the search criteria. When I try to run bigger requests, the application times out after the default 30 seconds. Does anyone know how to increase the timeout length? I've tried changing the Profile from this:

`web: gunicorn myapp:app --log-file=-`

to this:

`web: gunicorn myapp:app --timeout 1200`

but got nowhere.

But when I changed it to

`web: gunicorn myapp:app --timeout 5`

it timed out at 5 seconds

Answer (score 4):

Heroku has a limit of `30 sec` for any request to complete. If the request takes more than `30s` then it leads to `H12 error`.

So, in your case you can't set

> web: gunicorn myapp:app --timeout 1200

Ref: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#worker-timeouts and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#http-timeouts

Comment: Any Solution for this can't we manage the timeout on heroku